# snowflake read null from s3 json

Tags: json, amazon-s3, null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This seems like it should be easy, but for the life of me on a Friday night...

I have a json file i'm reading from s3

```
{"name":"bob", "currentTime":"null"}
```

I created a stage in snowflake.

When I do,

```
Select $1:name, $2:currentTime 
from @myStage/mydocument
```

I get as expected

$1:name   $2:currentTime

"bob"     "null"

I have a snowflake table

```
create table test_bob
(
name varchar
,currentTime TIMESTAMP_NTZ
)
```

But when I do

```
Copy into test_bob
Select $1:name, $2:currentTime 
    from @myStage/mydocument
```

I get an error,

```
Failed to cast variant value "null" to TIMESTAMP_NTZ
```

I tried using
NULL_IF
as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61435010/snowflake-external-table-failed-to-cast-variant-value-null-to-datetime-timestamp).

I tried using [STRIP_NULL_VALUES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-considerations-load.html#json-data-removing-null-values) as a file format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a string of "null" rather than a null value.  Did you try this?

```
Copy into test_bob
Select $1:name, NULLIF($2:currentTime::string,'null')::timestamp_ntz 
    from @myStage/mydocument
```

this should check the value of the string before trying to convert the json attribute object to a timestamp_ntz.